# Magento2: OnClick variation price not updated based on customer group

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, customer-group

I have configurable product.
Customer group wise variation price not updated.
It's update but once I add to cart, onclick it's not updated.

Can anyone have any idea.

Comment: \did you get solution for this,actually in my case also customer  group price not adding to the cart magento 2.3 version

Comment: if you have any idea please share with me.